# How to correctly deploy multi meteor instances WITH SSL on one digitalocean droplet using mup?

Tags: ssl, meteor, meteor-up

my mup.json config for first meteor instance:

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "111.222.333.444",
      "username": "root",
      "password": "mypass"
    }
  ],
  "setupMongo": true,
  "setupNode": true,
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.40",
  "setupPhantom": false,
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true,
  "appName": "myapp1",
  "app": "../myapp1",
  "env": {
    "PORT": 3001,
    "ROOT_URL": "https://my.domain.com"
  },
  "ssl": {
    "pem": "./ssl.pem"
  },
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

So after deployment I want to get access to this instance by https://my.domain.com:3001. Then with similar configuration I want to deploy second instance to same droplet and get access to it by https://my.domain.com:3002.

The problem is that after deployment accessing by https taking ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED, but accessing by http is OK.

How can I make it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I did it.

Firstly, I used `mupx`. But there I had troubles too. Later I found that my fault was writing same ports for different apps or protocols. So, there is working configurations of first and second apps:

```
{
  "servers": [{
    "host": "111.222.333.444",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "mypass",
    "env": {}
  }],
  "setupMongo": true,
  "appName": "myapp1",
  "app": "../myapp1",
  "env": {
    "PORT": 8000,
    "ROOT_URL": "http://my.domain.com"
  },
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15,
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true,
  "ssl": {
    "certificate": "../ssl/bundle.crt",
    "key": "../ssl/private.key",
    "port": 8001
  }
}

{
  "servers": [{
    "host": "111.222.333.444",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "mypass",
    "env": {}
  }],
  "setupMongo": true,
  "appName": "myapp2",
  "app": "../myapp2",
  "env": {
    "PORT": 8100,
    "ROOT_URL": "http://my.domain.com"
  },
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15,
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true,
  "ssl": {
    "certificate": "../ssl/bundle.crt",
    "key": "../ssl/private.key",
    "port": 8101
  }
}
```

`bundle.crt` and `private.key` are common for all apps.
Don't forget to use `mupx`.

So after

```
mupx setup
mupx deploy
```

We can get access for first app by

```
http://my.domain.com:8000
https://my.domain.com:8001
```

And for second app by

```
http://my.domain.com:8100
https://my.domain.com:8101
```

**EDIT**: accessing by http is not working. I don't know why, maybe it just for my configuration. But this feature I don't need, I need only https. So if you know how to fix, please, write.

**EDIT2**: it's alright, http access works. The reason was Chrome browser, it always redirects my domain from http to https. After cleaning browser history it do all good.